# How to make nil interface to struct in golang

Tags: go

I'm new in Golang.
I executed the code below. I get empty humans array in the end.
What should I do in func F?

For testing(monkeypatch) sake. I have to follow the way how the origin func is called.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Human struct {
    Name string
}

type Cat struct {
    Name string
}

func F(arr interface{}) {
    switch arr.(type) {
    case *[]*Human:
        arr = &[]*Human{{Name: "abc"}}
        arr = arr.(*[]*Human)

    case *[]*Cat:
        arr = &[]*Cat{{Name: "meow"}}
        arr = arr.(*[]*Cat)
    }

}

func main() {

    var humans []*Human
    F(&humans)
    fmt.Println(humans)

    var cats []*Cat
    F(&cats)
    fmt.Println(cats)
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/gyNZQMuALLd Use [short variable declaration](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) in the switch statement to retain the instance of the dynamic value that's stored inside the interface (e.g. `switch p := arr.(type) { ...`), then, to update the data to which the pointer points, use [pointer indirection](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Address_operators) (e.g. `*p = <expression>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, and the main issue cause as well, is that *Go* always uses **pass by value** (or copy of the value) when arguments are passed around to function or assigned to variables.

Your function `F` takes an `arr` argument:

```
func F(arr interface{}) {
    //...
}
```

When called from your `main` function, you are passing an `[]*Human` pointer as an argument, which values will be copied and fed to your function `F` for execution.

Going back to your function `F` body, the `arr` will be having the same value passed by main, which happens to be the address to the original `[]*Human` struct. Upon assigning a new value to `arr`:

```
func F(arr interface{}) {
    switch arr.(type) {
    case *[]*Human:
        arr = &[]*Human{{Name: "abc"}}
        // ...
    }
}
```

You are **assigning a new value to the *local* `arr`** variable and not to the original pointer, which remains, indeed, unchanged.

To update the value toward which the argument pointer is referring to, you should used the `dereferrence` symbol:

```
func F(arr interface{}) {
    switch arr := arr.(type) {
    case *[]*Human:
        *arr = []*Human{&Human{Name: "abc"}}
        fmt.Println(arr)
    // ...
    }
}
```

> Note the `switch arr := arr.(type)` statement which creates a new `arr` variable (shadowing the argument `arr`) with the `interface` dynamic type to be able to assign the proper value to it.